# iphone ISO-8859-1 encoder. how?

Tags: objective-c, url, encoding, iso-8859-1

The app sends uitextfield.text to a php file using POST.

php file has 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />`  (Norwegian/Swedish Letters.ÄÖÅ)

How to encode UITextField.text so that is readable online? 
I have tried several options. with no luck. Strange chars appear online.

```
     NSString* mess = [message.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding  allowLossyConversion:YES];
 [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding, and I won't be so sure about page conforming to encoding it specifies.